# Iterate over key/value pairs in associative array in D.

Tags: d

I don't know why I cannot find an answer to this on the web. It seems such a simple thing.

The associative array has a `byValue` member and a `byKey` member for iterating over the values and the keys. There's also a `byKeyValue` member for iterating over key/value pairs. It's just not clear what type it returns for iterating using `foreach`, and the compiler complains that `auto` is not good enough here.

The language docs (https://dlang.org/spec/hash-map.html) call it an "opaque type".

Any idea how to get the commented code working? Thank you!

```
int main(){
  int[string] contained;

  contained["foo"] = 4;
  contained["bar"] = 5;
  contained["gooey"] = 7;

  writeln("*by values*");
  foreach(int i ; contained.byValue){
    writeln(i);
  }

  writeln("*by keys*");
  foreach(string i ; contained.byKey){
    writeln(i);
  }

  // writeln("*by key/values*");
  //foreach(auto i ; contained.byKeyValue){
  //writeln(i.key,i.value);
  //}

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So first, you don't even strictly need a thing:

```
foreach(key, value; contained) {
   // use right here
}
```

But the .byKeyValue thing can be more efficient, so it is cool to use... just don't specify a type at all (in fact, you very rarely have to with D's foreach, and btw it is always wrong to use `auto` in the foreach statement - a common mistake since it is used in many other places...)

```
foreach(item; contained.byKeyValue()) {
   writeln(item.key, " ", item.value);
}
```

Also btw you can use `void main` if you always want `main` to return `0` - the language will do that automatically.

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly as advertised.

Comment: Interesting followup. Apparently the return type is explicitly hidden to encapsulate the types from user space. There's a section about it on the D wiki (https://wiki.dlang.org/Voldemort_types)